# Android Jsoup connect freezes thread

Tags: java, android, http, jsoup

I try to load data with Json.connect:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://google.com").timeout(2000).ignoreContentType(true).get();
```

It freezes my asynctask thread for a long time (Seems it won't stop). I also tried to remove "timeout(2000)", use another URL, remove "ignoreContentType(true)", but the problem appears again and again. I use android studio 2.0; in my build.gradle I use `compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.3'`. I also surrounded this block with `try { ... } catch (Throwable t) {}`, but it never goes to catch block. What is wrong here?

This code I use only for testing this class, neither `Log.d` nor `e.printStackTrace()` are never accessed. Android monitor shows permanent phone's cpu loading.

```
class WebLoader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        private WhatToLoad whatToLoad;

    public WebLoader(WhatToLoad whatToLoad) {
        this.whatToLoad = whatToLoad;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        return downloadUrl(params[0]);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(InputStream stream) {
        onWebResult(whatToLoad, stream);
    }

}

private static String downloadUrl(String myurl) {
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://google.com").timeout(2000).ignoreContentType(true).get();
            Log.d("jsoup1", doc.toString());
            return doc.toString();

        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Edit: The same problem happens when I run example from the official site:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse("<html><head><title>First parse</title></head>"
                + "<body><p>Parsed HTML into a doc.</p></body></html>");
        Element body = doc.body();
```

The logcat:

```
04-09 17:56:53.810 32615-32629/com.abc.def W/art: Suspending all threads took: 6.560ms
04-09 17:57:32.890 32615-32629/com.abc.def  W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.075ms
04-09 17:58:23.520 32615-32629/com.abc.def  W/art: Suspending all threads took: 6.361ms
04-09 17:58:28.530 32615-32629/com.abc.def W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.165ms
04-09 17:58:30.040 32615-32629/com.abc.def W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.637ms
04-09 17:58:30.540 32615-32629/com.abc.def W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.995ms
04-09 17:59:46.210 32615-32629/com.abc.def W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.289ms
```

Comment: Please, could you post a bigger piece of code?

Comment: Are you starting the `AsyncTask` ? From the code and description that you've posted, the problem is not evident. You will have to give us more details.

Comment: How are you starting the `WebLoader` task ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it. It seems there is a problem in android studio when you set breakpoint on

> Jsoup.parse

or

> Jsoup.connect

method. When I set breakpoint after theese methods, they run very fast, but if I set breakpoint on one of these methods, debugger stops before it and after pressing resume nothing happens.